# Pandas - List out data columns in new columns using Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I need to add new columns based on the groupby results. Take the following dataframe for exampe.

```
 ID      City      
 234x    Lima
 342x    Rica
 234x    Rio
 333x    NYC
 333x    SF
```

I have been about to use group_by to get the counts:

```
df_GroupBy = pd.DataFrame({'count':df.groupby([ "ID"]).size()}).reset_index()
```

This gives an output:

```
 ID       Count
234x       2
342x       1
333x       2
```

What I would like to do now is get this output:

```
 ID       City     City_2
234x       Lima     Rio
342x       Rica      
333x       NYC      SF
```

I have looked at both `Transform` and `map` but without much success. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
cities = df.groupby('ID')['City'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([city for city in x])).unstack()

         0    1
ID             
234x  Lima  Rio
333x   NYC   SF
342x  Rica  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the example provided. My main intent was to combine across multiple columns. For example, what would you suggest if the input data had ['ID', 'City1', 'City2'..'CityN'] columns?

Comment: This would be slightly different, probably adding a preparatory step - would you mind posting a new question with sample data so I can illustrate?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only post once per 90 minutes. Could you post your solution here? Thanks.